# Converting enum to string (and viceversa) using annotations

Tags: c#, .net, enums, type-conversion

Usually, when I find myself in need to convert an enum to a string or viceversa, I generally take advantage of the [Description Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

For instance, If I had the following enum:

```
public enum QueryOperations
{
     [Description("eq")]
     Equals,

     [Description("gt")]
     GreaterThan,

     [Description("lt")]
     LessThan
}
```

I would convert `QueryOperations.GreaterThan` to a string using its `DescriptionAttribute`'s value, i.e., it would be converted to `"gt"`.

In the same way, If i was to convert `"lt"` to `QueryOperations`, I would end up with `QueryOperations.LessThan`.

I really like this approach and never failed me so far. I think it is flexible, easy to understand and it is decoupled from the enum's value names.

However, quoting MSDN, a `DescriptionAttribute`:

> [...] Specifies a description for a property or event.

An example is shown:

```
[Description("The image associated with the control"),Category("Appearance")] 
public Image MyImage { get; set; }
```

This troubles me because it seems that the purpose of the `DescriptionAttribute` is semantically different to what I use it for.

Using Attributes to convert an enum is not a silly nor crazy idea, so my question is:

**Is it there an attribute specifically designed for this case?**

Something like:

```
public enum QueryOperations
{
    [StringRepresentation("eq")]
    Equals,
    //...
}
```

Comment: I believe any time I see this question come up, it's generally recommended to just use the Description tag as you stated.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z(v=vs.110).aspx) also says you can do this `string someValue = ((myEnum) 1).ToString();`. Problem with this is you can't utilize spaces.

Comment: using toString doesn't allow you to use spaces or punctuation... I"ve always used `Description` for this.

Comment: You could create your own custom attribute class to use instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no, there's not anything built in.

I think if the use case you presented is typical of what you need to do, you're better off creating a custom attribute. The `Description` attribute *can* be used in the way you're using it, but as you already mentioned, it's really meant to be a human-readable description.

For instance, you could do something like this:

```
    public class StringRepresentationAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public StringRepresentationAttribute(string stringRep)
        {
            this._stringRep = stringRep;
        }

        public string StringRepresentation { get { return _stringRep; } }

        private readonly string _stringRep;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return StringRepresentation;
        }
    }
```

Then have something like this as an extension method:

```
public static string GetStringRepresentation(this Enum en)
        {
            Type type = en.GetType();

            MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

            if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
            {
                object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringRepresentationAttribute), false);

                if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
                {
                    return ((StringRepresentationAttribute)attrs[0]).StringRepresentation;
                }
            }

            return en.ToString();
        }
```

The your enum becomes:

```
public enum QueryOperations
{
     [StringRepresentation("eq")]
     Equals,

     [StringRepresentation("gt")]
     GreaterThan,

     [StringRepresentation("lt")]
     LessThan
}
```

And now you can:

`string operatorAsString = QueryOperations.LessThan.GetStringRepresentation();`

Comment: How would you actually use this? Just like `[Description("Some Description")]` except it'd be `[StringRepresentation("Some Desc")]` ?

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `[Description]` is intended for human consumption.

Comment: @sab669 yes, see my edit for an example of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use extension methods. This article http://weblogs.asp.net/grantbarrington/enumhelper-getting-a-friendly-description-from-an-enum covers the topic more in depth

here's a quick peek at the extension method:

```
 public static class EnumHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve the description on the enum, e.g.
        /// [Description("Bright Pink")]
        /// BrightPink = 2,
        /// Then when you pass in the enum, it will retrieve the description
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="en">The Enumeration</param>
        /// <returns>A string representing the friendly name</returns>
        public static string GetDescription(Enum en)
        {
            Type type = en.GetType();

            MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

            if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
            {
                object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

                if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
                {
                    return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
                }
            }

            return en.ToString();
        }

    }
```

You would get the description like so:

```
MyEnum.EnumsValue.GetDescription();
```

Going back the other way, you could use Parse or TryParse built in the .NET framework:

```
//Parse
MyEnum enumValue = (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), enumValueString);

//TryParse
MyEnum enumValue;
Enum.TryParse(enumValueString, out enumValue));
```

Comment: ha! I just added the extension method as I was editing my answer. +1!