# How to parse enum from value of StringValue attribute

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Not able to parse into enum object from its StringValue attribute.

enum:

```
public enum StatusColor
{
    [StringValue("#FFFFFF")]
    None,

    [StringValue("#5DB516")]
    Green,

    [StringValue("#F3212A")]
    Red,

    [StringValue("#FFFFFF")]
    White
}
```

parsing try 1

```
string inputHtmlColor = "#F3212A"; // input
StatusColor outColor; // output
Enum.TryParse(inputHtmlColor , true, out outColor);
```

parsing try 2:

```
string inputHtmlColor = "#F3212A"; //input
StatusColor outColor = Enum.Parse(typeof(StatusColor), inputHtmlColor, true);
```

Both code is not working, codes always selecting `StausColor.None` (the first one). How can I get the right `StatusColor` enum object?

Comment: Let me know if the linked question doesn't answer yours (by tagging me in a comment `@john`) and I'll reopen your question.

Comment: Hi @John, the answer you suggested is opposite of what I want. The answer is about from object to its attribute value while I already have attribute value and I and to convert it into enum object.

Comment: Please reopen my question.

Comment: Ah, understood. My bad!

Comment: One question. What is the meaning of the square bracket here?

Comment: @kame `[ ]` denotes an [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/).

Comment: Hi @kame, ```[ ]``` is similar like ```@``` annotation in Java, if you are from Java background.

Comment: I literally just did this today. Search for “convert to enum from description attribute” and change the code to use that attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting enum to string (and viceversa) using annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189481/converting-enum-to-string-and-viceversa-using-annotations)

Comment: @δev: The relatively tricky part of the code is finding all the attribute values in the enum. It should be reasonably straightforward to change that code to go the other way round. Have you tried to do so? If so, how far did you get, and what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what working with minimal change:

Util class:

```
private static IDictionary<string, StatusColor> _statusColorByHtml = Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusColor)).Cast<StatusColor>().ToDictionary(k => k.GetStringValue(), v => v);
public static StatusColor GetStatusColor(string htmlColor)
{
    _statusColorByHtml.TryGetValue(htmlColor, out StatusColor color);
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
public StatusColor GetColor(string color)
{
    return
        Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusColor))
            .Cast<StatusColor>()
            .First(x => ((StringValueAttribute)typeof(StatusColor)
                        .GetField(x.ToString())
                        .GetCustomAttribute(typeof(StringValueAttribute))).Value == color);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a reverse lookup dictionary that takes the enum value and returns a matching enum value:

```
public static IDictionary<TKey, TEnum> GetReverseEnumLookup<TEnum, TKey, TAttribute>(Func<TAttribute, TKey> selector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    where TEnum: struct, IConvertible // pre-C#7.3
    // where TEnum : System.Enum // C#7.3+
    where TAttribute: System.Attribute
{
    // use the default comparer for the dictionary if none is specified
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;

    // construct a lookup dictionary with the supplied comparer
    Dictionary<TKey, TEnum> values = new Dictionary<TKey, TEnum>(comparer);

    // get all of the enum values
    Type enumType = typeof(TEnum);
    var enumValues = typeof(TEnum).GetEnumValues().OfType<TEnum>();

    // for each enum value, get the corresponding field member from the enum
    foreach (var val in enumValues)
    {
        var member = enumType.GetMember(val.ToString()).First();

        // if there is an attribute, save the selected value and corresponding enum value in the dictionary
        var attr = member.GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>();
        if (attr != null) 
        {
            values[selector(attr)] = val;
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

I've made this method as generic as possible so that it can apply to many use cases. Usage in your case would look like this:

```
var lookup = GetReverseEnumLookup<StatusColor, string, StringValueAttribute>(v => v.Value, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // I figure you want this to be case insensitive
```

And then you can store the lookup statically somewhere, and lookup values like this:

```
StatusColor color;
if (lookup.TryGetValue("#ffffff", out color))
{
    Console.WriteLine(color.ToString());
}
else
{
    // not found
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/QXLAN96655)

Comment: Hi @John, not an straight answer but I really liked the idea to have relationship Dictionary <string, enum> and look inside it. May be I'll create my own and for case insensitivity I'll look by converting the key case to same I have stored. Thanks.!

Comment: @δev I just figured you were likely to need some degree of performance (which a dictionary will provide). I dislike the alternative methods I've seen for this since they often evaluate the entire enum using reflection every single time you need to convert a value. It works, but it's not very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your calling code:

```
string inputHtmlColor = "#F3212A";
StatusColor outColor = inputHtmlColor.GetEnumFromString<StatusColor>();
```

That's how you would call the below extension method.

- I used and modified the below extension method which came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4367868/9533368)

```
public static class EnumEx
{
    public static T GetEnumFromString<T>(this string stringValue)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        foreach (var field in type.GetFields())
        {
            var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
                typeof(StringValueAttribute)) as StringValueAttribute;
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                if (attribute.Value == stringValue)
                    return (T)field.GetValue(null);
            }
            else
            {
                if (field.Name == stringValue)
                    return (T)field.GetValue(null);
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("Not found.", "stringValue");
        // or return default(T);
    }
}
```

**note on the Attribute:**

I defined my attribute like this:

```
public class StringValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public StringValueAttribute(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

If your `StringValueAttribute` is defined differently, feel free to update your question to include that type definition, and I'll update my answer if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have created one method for that as below

```
StringEnum.GetStringValue(Pass Your enum here)
```

Call this function which is created in common class

```
public static string GetStringValue(Enum value)
        {
            string output = null;
            try
            {
                Type type = value.GetType();

                if (_stringValues.ContainsKey(value))
                    output = (_stringValues[value] as StringValueAttribute).Value;
                else
                {
                    ////Look for our 'StringValueAttribute' in the field's custom attributes
                    FieldInfo fi = type.GetField(value.ToString());
                    StringValueAttribute[] attrs = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringValueAttribute), false) as StringValueAttribute[];
                    if (attrs.Length > 0)
                    {
                        _stringValues.Add(value, attrs[0]);
                        output = attrs[0].Value;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

            return output;

        }
```

Comment: Hi @rvchauhan, this is not what I'm looking for. I already have GetStringValue method to convert from object to string attrb value. I want just opposite of it. Want from String attrb value to enum object. Thanks.!